# Why is queryselector not clicking class element in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I would like to have a button clicked when I open a poker table. I am doing this using a Chrome Extension since it is a Javascript poker site.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<body class="skin-mark toolbar-open  table-active">
    <div class="tile-tables"></div>
.....
</body>
```

My code looks like this:

```
console.log("Table open, now tiling tables")

document.querySelector('.tile-tables').click();
```

I am wondering why it does not click the button. When I select the `tile-tables` class in the DOM this shows up in the styles menu:

```
.tile-tables {
background-size: 100%;
background-image: url(../images/table/multi-table-button.png);
```

Comment: Are you sure that when the extension attempts to click the div, it does exist in DOM? Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: `divs` are not inherently clickable, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: No. I am not sure. I am very new to Javascript as you can probably tell. The console shows `Table open, now tiling tables`

Comment: The `div` is a button in the window. I am trying to click that button on window open.

Comment: There is little we can do to help without a [mcve]. Try debugging yourself. There is some helpful information about debugging here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: Have you created a task which has to be performed on clicking that `tile-tables` `div`

Comment: @JonP Wut? Divs are not clickable? For sure they are, there just is not any default action, though.

Comment: My assumption was that `.click()` was the task to be performed if that is what you are asking @Exterminator

Comment: I mean how will he know that `.click()` is performed?

Comment: Could it be clicking before the page loads?

Comment: @Teemu well `divs` are not interactive in the same way as butons, check boxes, links etc. Click on a link it does something, not much normally happens when you click on a `div` . Some elements are better targets for click actions than a `div`. (Trying to keep this simple and not get into event propagation/bubbling)

Comment: @Exterminator i will take a wild guess and say there should be a statement to check if the element exists?? Tbh I am a little lost.

Comment: What would happen if you were to manually click on the "tile-tables" div? Note that a `div` is not normally considered a `button`.  What do you get if you add `console.log(document.querySelector('.tile-tables').length)` after your existing console log?

document.querySelector('.tile-tables').click();

Comment: So what it does is resizes all windows to fit proportionately inside the screen. I think I figured it out. The `z-index: 10000000;` Would this make it not clickable? I am reading elsewhere that a high z-index would do that as it causes elements to overlap. What I dont understand is why a mouse-click tiles the windows but this cant be done through code.

Comment: What is most likely happening is your code is being executed before the element has been added to the DOM (see my previous console.log suggestion) or your code is being executed before and event handlers have been assigned to the element. In its bare bones, your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/v6waodqe/

Comment: I added `.delay(5000)` but that did not work either. I am at a loss =D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181314/discussion-between-jon-p-and-6seven8).

Answer (score 0):

The class is taken for a `div` so you may call through `tagname.classname` like bellow:

```
document.querySelector('div.tile-tables').click();
```